# How to hook into Spring Security authentication process?

Tags: spring, spring-security, kotlin

Currently I have this trivial configuration:

```
// Kotlin code
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/entry")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
        .usernameParameter("usr")
        .passwordParameter("pwd")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
        .failureHandler { request, response, exception -> 
            // Can't figure out what to enter here (see below).
        }
}
```

If authentication fails, I have two requirements:

1. Flash error message into the session (avoiding 'error' param in query string). It seems I can't inject `RedirectAttributes` into this lambda; is there a workaround?
2. I want to send back the login (but not the password) that user entered before submitting login form, in order to repopulate the field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/entry")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
            .usernameParameter("usr")
            .passwordParameter("pwd")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .failureHandler { request, response, _ ->
                request.session.setAttribute("loginError", "Login Error!")
                request.session.setAttribute("failedUsername", request.getParameter("usr"))
                response.sendRedirect("/entry")
            }
    }
}
```

Then, you have to set up login controller to customize serving of login form:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/entry")
internal class LoginController {
    @GetMapping
    fun getLoginForm(session: HttpSession, model: Model): String {
        if (session.getAttribute("loginError") != null) {
            model.addAttribute("loginError", "Login Error!")
            session.removeAttribute("loginError")
            model.addAttribute("failedUsername", session.getAttribute("failedUsername"))
            session.removeAttribute("failedUsername")
        }
        return "login"
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `loginError` and `failedUsername` model attributes in your templates:

```
<div th:if="${loginError}">Incorrect login/password</div>
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" name="usr" th:value="${failedUsername}">
```

Basically we are emulating "flashing" messages into session. We carry these messages in the session and remove them as soon as they are read and passed on into the model. It’s possible that redirect will go wrong and messages will remain in the session, but they are harmless on their own, plus they will be removed the next time user visits `/entry` page.

As a result, now there is no `?error` in page URL, and the user is not required to retype username.